# Selenium Webdriver - Clicking on a button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The scenario is that when I try to login with invalid user name or password, I get a pop up System Message telling me what I entered was incorrect. At first, I tried with `switchto().alert()`; but the system told me there was no Alert so it could not carry on, this pop up message can also be closed if I click on a random place of the page. The HTML code is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

I am still unable to click on that Close button with this line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Close')]")).click();
```

Some correction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please try to add some wait methods after clicking on login button and before clicking on close button

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I am wondering why I didn't think of this earlier. Problem solved. :)

Comment: @k.s.Karthik Please post your comment as an answer so OP can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you @JeffC :). Added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add some wait methods after clicking on login button and before clicking on close button

Answer (score 0):

Use anyone of wait methods. for a quick u can use Thread.Sleep() as well